# Why doesn't this two way data binding work?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, node.js

I have this controller. Whenever I try to bind my $scope.things to my received JSON from the server, my View wont update. In fact, if I left my `push(newThing)` and uncomment my calls to `getAllThings()`, my view will display the data and, in less than a second, will remove it.

The problem is: in the server side (Morgan running with Node and MongoDB), I'm printing out the json object before it is passed to my client and the object is correct, it DOES have the latest created object.

I'm willing to use push instead of making another request to server to fetch data, but I'm really upset about this topic. Another interesting thing it that my second, third and consequent calls to `insertThing()` will properly update my view. It made feel kind of clueless. I can provide more code if needed.

Controller:

```
$scope.insertThing= function(newThing){
    $scope.things.push(newThing);
    $http.post('http://localhost:8080/things', newThing)
    .then(function(res){
        //$scope.getAllThings();
        delete $scope.newThing;
    }, function(res){

    });
    //$scope.getAllThings();    
};

$scope.getAllThings = function(userDpt){
    $http.post('http://localhost:1234/things/dpt/', {userDpt: userDpt})
    .then(function(res){
        $scope.things = res.data;
    }, function(res){

    });
};
```

Node Server with Mongoose:

```
app.post('/things/dpt', function(req, res){
var department = req.body.dpt;
var things= {};
TicketModel.find({ fromDpt: department}, 
    function(err,obj){
        res.json(obj);
    });
});
```

Markup:

```
<tr ng-repeat="thing in things">
  <td> {{ thing.toDpt}} </td>
  <td> {{ thing.status }}</td>
  <td> {{ thing.deadline }}</td>
  <td><button class="btn close" data-ng-click="deleteThing(thing._id)">&times;</button></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wknqxqmq/1/ ?

Comment: In your `getAllThings` function, where is `data.json` coming from?  I don't see it defined anywhere.

Comment: It sounds like an issue with the order in which you are loading the data and then calling your insertThing method. It is difficult to tell with the code you have supplied. We could do with seeing more.

Comment: Code added to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this was long time ago.

All this code was fully refactored. The problem was with the assyncronous behavior of JavaScript. Sometimes, the getAllThings() function would finish before the delete line and the new fetched data would just vanish after being received.

The way around this problem is to add another callback after the http request.